# Is this a valid regular language expression for a binary string? Can it be condensed into something more concise?

Tags: regular-language

The regular expression is:

```
(10) U ((10(0 U 1))*10)
```

The language I am trying to write is this:(q2 is the accept state and {0,1} is the langauge)

```
(q0,0)=q3
(q0,1)=q1
(q1,0)=q2   — accept state
(q1,1)=q3
(q2,0)=q0
(q2,1)=q0
(q3,0)=q3
(q3,1)=q3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after here. Could you provide the input text and the expected output?

Comment: I am trying to convey a regular language with a regular expression. the state transitions show how the definite finite automate is defined.

Comment: I updated the tag and title. Around here, “regular expression” almost ubiquitously refers to the practical application as it relates to text.. the title still reads funny though, trying to avoid the direct “regular expression” pair..

Comment: You may want to post this question on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/#

Comment: okay, thanks everyone! ill post it there.

Comment: @jdaz: [cstheory.se] is an academic site intended for "research-level questions in theoretical computer science". A "research-level" question is one which might be asked in the course of working on a Ph.D. thesis, or something similar. This is not such a question and should not be redirected to that site.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying